# How configure Bind (DNS) server to respond internet requests

Tags: domain-name-system, centos7, bind

I'm new to Bind so please forgive any "silly" questions.
I've configured a Bind Server on CentOS-7, Server name CentOS-DC (10.64.33.115).
I've also configured 3 CentOS-7 Clients

- CentOS-App-01 10.60.161.99
- CentOS-DB-01 10.60.161.169
- CentOS-Web-01 10.60.161.229

Everything resolves correctly internally.

The issue arises when I try browsing the Web.
I've added in forwarder addresses to /etc/named.conf but am still unable to browse the web.

Below is my /etc/named.conf file

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//
// See the BIND Administrator's Reference Manual (ARM) for details about the
// configuration located in /usr/share/doc/bind-{version}/Bv9ARM.html

options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 10.64.33.115;}; ### Master DNS IP ###
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory   "/var/named";
        dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { localhost; 10.60.161.0/24; };
        allow-transfer  { localhost; 10.64.33.115; };

        /*
         - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
         - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable
           recursion.
         - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access
           control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
           cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification
           attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
           reduce such attack surface
        */
    recursion yes;
        allow-recursion {localhost; 10.60.161.0/24; };

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;

        forwarders {
                10.73.240.235;
                152.62.196.10;
        };

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
    channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "CorkCompute.local" IN {
        type master;
        file "forward.CorkCompute";
        allow-update { none; } ;
};

zone "161.60.10" IN {
        type master;
        file "reverse.CorkCompute";
        allow-update { none; } ;
};


zone "." IN {
    type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

thanks

Comment: Read [formatting tools](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and update your question accordingly. This is unreadable.

Comment: I was just about to reformat it for him when I saw your comment. :)

Comment: Thanks guys, i'll try to reformat now, just going through the URL posted by Sven

Comment: You list `10.73.240.235` as a forwarder. That's an internal IP address so you own that DNS server as well?

Comment: that's correct Tom, 10.73.240.235 & 152.62.196.10 are internal DNS Servers. If I use these as the DNS Servers for any of the Clients, accessing the internet is fine. If I set the DNS Server on the Clisent to 10.64.33.115 (CentOS-DC, running Bind) they cannot access the internet. But, nslookup, dig, ping NAME, etc... work internally

Comment: Using the same instance as both a recursive nameserver and an authoritative one is not recommended. That can creates problems, security or otherwise and will make debugging more complicated. You should really separate the two services.

Comment: "The issue arises when I try browsing the Web" this is not enough for an explanation. What happens exactly? How are your clients configured DNS wise? Did you try direct DNS queries with `dig` ? Which ones? What results?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out with the help of a Linux guy in work.
Even though I had configured Forwarders, I hadn't told the server to actually forward anything. Below is the updates code

```
forwarders {
    10.73.240.235;
    152.62.196.10;
};
forward only;
```

Comment: Strange, I would expect that once you define forwarders, the statement `forward` would apply with its default value  `first`. Changing `forward first` to `forward only` should not have an impact on your configuration.

Answer (score -1):

10.0.0.0/8 is an IP range dedicated for 'Private Use Networks' (RFCs 1918, 5735 and 6303). The same is for networks 192.168.0.0/16 fnd 172.16.0.0/12. This addresses do not routed via internet and can not be accessed from the outer networks directly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Kondybas but I don't believe using a Private IP Address is the cause of this issue. I'm able to browse the internet from these Clients when using standard company DNS Servers. The issue is only when I use the Bind Server as the DNS source

Comment: @Jason Ok. Your computer is somewhere outside your private network and has an IP address 77.88.99.11. There is lot of networks and lot of routers between your computer and the server bind is placed on. How can your computer tell the IP 10.64.33.115 you have assigned to your server from the IP 10.64.33.115 I have assigned to my host in the my own private network?

Comment: Hi Kondybas, my background is networking (Cisco). From that perspective, everything is 100%. in this environment, if I configure one of my clients with an existing DNS Server (which is on a different subnet also), it is possible to browse the internet. The problem starts when 10.64.33.115 is used as the DNS Server, at this poing the Clients can no longer browse the internet. I believe I need to configure named.conf on 10.64.33.115 with forwarder addresses but, even with this configured, the Clients still are unable to browse the Web